# How to run user code that might be unsafe?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am writing a program that will interpret and run some user code written in Javascript in C#.  How do I go about running with hard limit in running time?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?  Can you elaborate on exactly what you want to have happen, and what you have already tried?  If you want to execute Javascript, you could probably write the user's input to a .JS file and then open it.  It would be helpful if you could specify the exact behavior you want.

Comment: How do I set a time limit on the JS code?

Comment: What do you mean by *time limit* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running *user* code; **EVER;** is not safe (see SQL injection, obligatory reference to [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/)). There is no way to *make* it safe (apart from sandboxing, at which point you aren't running their code on your computer any more). See the 10 immutable laws of security ([TechNet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rhalbheer/2011/06/16/ten-immutable-laws-of-security-version-2-0/))

That said, you could use the overload of `Process.WaitForExit` that takes an `int` (MSDN) to "timeout" and kill the process after a time period (10s in the example):

```
Process myVeryUnsafeProc = new Process();
myVerUnsafeProc.Start();
if (!myVeryUnsafeProc.WaitForExit(10000))
{
   myVeryUnsafeProc.Kill();
}
```

Note that the javascript could have killed your monitoring process and made this whole exercise pointless. Did I mention you just *can't* do this safely?

Comment: This is what I am looking for.